# Ansible specific log details collection

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

Ansible has logging plugins to send the data to log stash, log DNA, etc. But is it possible to log specific details like person who ran the playbook, on what servers playbook was executed , IP addresses. I am trying to understand whether is there any module specifically for logging.

Answer (score 0):

I bet the thing you want is [ARA](https://github.com/openstack/ara#readme) from the OpenStack folks. I have been using it for a while and find it a ton easier to read than wading through a sea of log output.

That said, you may also be happier with [AWX, or "Tower" (their commercial verion)](https://github.com/ansible/awx#readme). Using AWX would have the benefit of *enforcing* access to the playbooks, versus asking people to correctly configure their `ansible.cfg` to use ARA.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Under what circumstances is that happening, and what does that have to do with what you asked?